# No Errors Highlighted in Orchestration, but Build Fails

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2013r2

I have an orchestration defined and no errors are present, but I see #error statements in the orchestration (in XML view):

> #error "Message Type 'X' does not exists or is not valid

However, I know message type exists; I see the schema and see the CS file with the class/XML schema defined.  It was also just working the other day, but now fails in development.  I see other project errors as:

> identifier 'XPortType' does not exist in 'Project' are you missing an assembly reference?

However I can see the port in my orchestration and it is not marked as an error...

> identifier 'XMessage' does not exist in 'unnamed'; are you missing an assembly reference?

XMessage is defined in my orchestration; I can see it there without any errors.

I don't know why I am getting these errors??  Everything is clearly defined without errors in the orchestration.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem:[Visual Studio 2008 with Biztalk 2009 Missing assembly reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2df94010-5755-4982-a02d-81f8feb51fda/visual-studio-2008-with-biztalk-2009-missing-assembly-reference?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Specifically, the accepted answer resolution of:

- Make backup of .odx file
- Open .odx file in text editor
- Remove everything after the line '#endif // __ DESIGNER_DATA'
- Save and close the file
- Reopen in Visual studio
- Change a little thing (like adding a line or space to an expression shape) to have the code generated again.

Once I removed the content and regenerated, then remapped the ports, it all came back.  The scary part is why it broke in the first place...

Comment: Sometimes it's enough to just edit an expression shape (add whitespace or something), close it, and save (avoiding the need to restart visual studio or manually edit the file).  This is a pretty common bug with the Orchestration Designer unfortunately.